# How to remove all HTML elements after the <header> using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website where, under a certain condition, I want to remove every element after the `<header>` tag. How can I do this with javascript?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
</head>
<body>

<main>
        <!-- header start -->
        <header>
        ....
        </header>

    <!--- a bunch of sections, divs, etc that I want to not show sometimes -->


    <!--- But I need these scripts to run, and I want to add my javascript to main.js -->
    <script src="./js/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>

</main>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? See [ask].

Comment: Ah my bad, I didn't think it was worth it. I was just manually doing `Element.remove()` on everything in the particular `if` case in my javascript.

Comment: Folks expect to see that you made an effort and didn't just ask for free code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handy-dandy chainable `:not` selector could be useful. It doesn't remove elements by *order*, as you asked, but maybe it's a solution here.

```js
const badEls = document.querySelectorAll('main > :not(header):not(script)');

badEls.forEach(el => {
  el.remove();
});
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <header>Header</header>
    <div>Div</div>
    <section>Section</section>
    <div>Div</div>

    <script src="./js/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
  </main>
</body>
```

Otherwise you'll have to work through the nodeList and check nodeType until you get to a script. This would be safer if you have other elements after the scripts.

```js
// get all siblings of the header element
const els = document.querySelectorAll('main > header ~ *');
let elsToRemove = [];
let i = 0;

// add all elements to our array until we reach a script
do {
  elsToRemove.push(els[i]);
  i++;
} while (els[i].nodeName !== 'SCRIPT');


// and remove them
elsToRemove.forEach(el => {
  el.remove();
});
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <header>Header</header>
    <div>Div</div>
    <section>Section</section>
    <div>Div</div>

    <script src="./js/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>

    <div>Div after scripts</div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to actually remove the content, or does hiding it with css work?

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('main').classList.toggle('hide-content');
})
```

```css
.hide-content > :not(header) {
  display: none;
}

/* light styling; not relevant */
main > * {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    <div>Header</div>
    <button>Toggle Content</button>
  </header>
  <div>other stuff</div>
  <section>more stuff</section>
  <div>other stuff</div>
  <section>more stuff</section>  
</main>
```